# Use git,composer,oh-my-zsh inside Docker container (UID/GID issue)

Tags: git, docker, composer-php, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm currently working on a custom dev environment on Docker. I used to build a "tools" one which regroups Git, Composer, Symfony, Java.. The main goal is to not have thoses packages installed on the host (I can switch fastly to host from host with a container)

My tools container which I use is based on debian:jessie ; using "oh-my-zsh" and mostly Git and composer for this part. My git repositories are mounted from the host.

two issues here which are related:

**Issue 1**

As running a docker is obviously in root 0:0, I have UID/GID issue about my local user host (default 1000:1000) and the container running Git or Composer. Container is running it as root(0:0) and most of time ruined localhost permissions.

I already tried some workarounds with Gosu (https://github.com/tianon/gosu) and/or playing with envvars and Dockerfile parameters about creating users (RUN useradd, USER user....). Still fail on this part.

**Issue 2**

Same problem with oh-my-zsh. Considering it's using root, if I change the user I get a permission denied inside the container.

Let's considering this Dockerfile as the one I currently used to build the container :

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y bc zsh curl wget git tig gettext-base vim nano

# Install Oh My Zsh
RUN wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh || true
ADD .zshrc /root/.zshrc

# Install Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" &&  php composer-setup.php --filename=composer --install-dir=bin && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3"


ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/zsh"]
```

I started it using a shell alias like :

```
alias tools="docker run --rm -it -v *GIT_FOLDER* -v *OTHER_VOLUMES* --network=dev -h tools tools"
```

My point is to still use the alias (UX constraint) and get a workaround about using zsh as another user <==> using git and composer without having UID/GID issues between container volume and local host folder.

I start to have no idea how to work around this. Any suggests ? Thx a lot !